# List all pages from MySite

Tags: 2013, permissions, my-site

I am a farm-level administrator in a SharePoint 2013 farm and I want to view all sub sites of MySites. The problem is that I don't have the permission to access the site contents of the users in the farm. Is there any way to override these permissions as a farm admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CA -> Manage Web Application -> User Policy -> Add the user and it should be fixed